# onblur event fires only on alternate input fields in Firefox

Tags: javascript, html

After each form input element, I need to do a verification using the same script.
I used `onblur=myFunction("name")` (where `nam`e is the `name=` attribute for the form field) in each form element so when the user presses `<tab>` the cursor advances to the next entry field.

The problem is that Firefox (Linux 93.0 - 64 bit) fires the *onblur* event ONLY on odd-numbered form input fields. The even numbered ones lose focus without executing the event handler.
Sometimes, but not always, I can force the event to fire by clicking on a different form input field, or rotating out and back into the form. This is very consistent.

Here are two example sequential fields from the real form, '*fname*' fires the event, '*lname*' does not.
There is a total of 17 named input fields.  The style for these fields does not reflect the "unfocused" state after the cursor exits the field either.

```html
<label for="fname" class="shipping">First Name</label>
<input type="text" class="shipping" name="fname" id="fname" maxlength=24 size=20 placeholder="First Name" autofocus onBlur=field_check("fname")>
<label for="lname" class="shipping">Last Name</label>
<input type="text" class="shipping" name="lname" id="lname" maxlength=48 size=30 placeholder="Last Name" required onBlur=field_check("lname")>
```

How to fix this issue?

Comment: Please share `field_check`'s content too, and how you integrate it in the page. FWIW, it's a "no-repro" for me on Firefox 93.0 on macOS. https://jsfiddle.net/p1sj9qnx/1/

Comment: Also, instead of doing this: 'onblur=myFunction("name")' you should do: 'onblur=myFunction(this.name)'.  If you ever change the name you don't have to remember to change the function too.

Comment: At the moment, field_check() is a rather trivial prove that it works sort of thing:  function field_check(the_field)
{
 var the_value= document.getElementById(the_field).value;

        alert("field_check--->" + the_field + " contains " + the_value); return true; 
}
Thanks for the suggestion Charles; there are alot of fields so when I get this to work I will do that.

Comment: I found a number of references (all old) to problems with the focus events on Firefox so I changed all the onBlur events to onChange but the results are the same, only alternate form input fields fire the event.  ALL of the fields WILL fire the event at various times if you use the mouse to muddle the field order but only every second try!  Has anyone any ideas at all?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those who responded, even though nobody had an answer.  I did a lot of testing and found that the problem is interference between the CSS styles and the inline onBlur, onChange, etc.  When these are removed all works as expected although I can no longer determine when a field has been completed.  Testing, I found that Firefox (Linux and Windows) will respond to every second event, so alternate lines do not get styled and do not report data entry.  Chrome on Windows will hang after the third field is entered and the pop up cannot be dismissed without closing the browser.  An old version of Internet Explorer (!) worked exactly as expected but I couldn't test either Edge or Safari since I don't have them installed here.
Overall, there seems to be some disconnect between the documentation and the implementation on mainstream browsers but I have run out of time to try and find it so I'll have to find a "plan B".